# Jquery Slider that Supports Image Categories

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a Jquery gallery plugin that supports dynamic switching of images via category-- so if someone clicks category 1's link, all of the images in the slider are replaced by images from category 1.

Alternatively, It'd be fine if all the images from all available categories loaded in the slider so long as I had a way to make the slideshow stop at a certain slide and resume sliding from the beginning. For example, if each category has 5 images, I'd like to be able to tell the slideshow to stop at slide 5 and start cycling over again from slide 1 until the user clicks the link for category #2, which will jump the slideshow to slide #6 and start the process over again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a pretty tailored solution for a plugin to offer.

You could easily get the desired result with a few http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ and then using show/hide based on category. Could even use jquery ui tabs..

Comment: A thousand thank yous, sir. This did exactly what I wanted. :)